# Software for taking handwritten notes

Tags: drawing, handwriting, note-taking

I am using Wacom tablet in Windows 7, mainly with Photoshop. I Was
wondering if there is a good program to take notes, draw, save, print
and so on that could be run in the background. A Google search yeilds no
results aside from advertisements and spam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I can think of is [Microsoft Onenote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/), but OneNote is better IMO.